# How to make HTTP request (to query json data/API) on Excel for Mac OSX

Tags: excel, vba, http, request

I am new to using VBA inside of Excel. I want to query some data to populate in on my excel worksheet (table).
However, in many tutorials (code sample) I have found online, I am missing so library/dependency. Here is a code sample where I have  `Can't find project or library` for `Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` error when I run it.

```
Sub BasicGETRequest()

    Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim reqURL As String
    
    reqURL = "https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/vba-macros/videos/vba-scrape-websites/"
    
    req.Open "GET", reqURL, False
    
    req.Send
    
    If req.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox req.Status & " - " & req.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Debug.Print req.responseText
    'ParseWiseOwlVideos req.responseText
    SaveHTMFile req.responseText
    
End Sub
```

The excel version I am using: Version 16.40 (20081000).
My Mac OS version: macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

The required object reference is:
**Microsoft XML, v6.0**

Comment: How can I have it installed?

Comment: I have been/went at tools>reference but i am not finding this library

Comment: What other library can i sue to make http request?

Comment: Please watch this tutorial.

Comment: I am on a mac. I don't have internet explorer. I have tried with edge. it is still nothing

Comment: Try this Jason parser  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON  , over there you will find  samples and video and support for Mac

Comment: @xShen I am fine with parsing a json object.
Want I want is to be able to retrieve this JSON data for manipulation (display it on excel sheet/table).

Comment: what's the exact line of code needed to use it on a mac?